# Embed the one rails app into another

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two apps AppA and AppB which point to same database, but different tables, now I want to embed AppB into AppA, when service of AppA starts up, I could access AppB's page by submenu of AppA.

so what kind of technique I could utilize to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines

or

[Differences between railties and engines in Ruby On Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497834/differences-between-railties-and-engines-in-ruby-on-rails-3)

They are helpful.

However, our case looks mostly like this, [Combining two Rails applications into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591484/combining-two-rails-applications-into-one)